# This binary series in java using bitwise operators

Tags: java, binary, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

Please refer to this version of Edit as the previous ones are ambiguous - thanks

I am looking to generate a binary series that is dependent on a number in a String.

There are 2 types of digits. 7's & 9's and **non** 7's & **non** 9's.

so, for example a number 29 will have the exact same output as 39 or 49 or 59  but **79** as both the digits fall under 7's and 9's.

Let's just call it as;

Group 1 : **NON** 7's and 9's

Group 2 : 7's and 9's

The string being 22,33, 23,42,21, etc. will provide the same output as all the digits combinations fall under group 1.

The string being 77, 79, 99, 97 will provide the same output as all the digits combinations fall under group 2.

The difference between group 1 and group 2 are the number of active bits.
group 1 has 3 bits that we will be shifting from and to while group 2 has 4 bits.

so the number 29 would produce

```
2 = 001
9 = 0001
```

here is the output required.

```
String s = "23";
```

output:

```
001 001
001 010
001 100
010 001
010 010
010 100
100 001
100 010
100 100
```

Another example:

```
String s = "93";
```

output:

```
0001 001
0001 010
0001 100
0010 001
0010 010
0010 100
0100 001
0100 010
0100 100
1000 001
1000 010
1000 100
```

Similarly,

```
String s = "274";
```

output:

```
001 0001 001
001 0001 010
001 0001 100
001 0010 001 // the group 1 digits will complete the circulation of 3 bits where as group 2 digits will complete for 4 bits.
    ...
```

We can store them in different ararys, print them, etc. I would take care from the rest, but the only thing I can't seem to figure out right now is how to generate such output.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does the string value affect things, or is only the length meaningful?  BTW this is called "counting", starting with a nonzero value.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten to put it in the question before, just edited.

The String if is 23 - the output can be of 3 bits, the first one will always be considered zero, but for 7 and 9, the output will be considered of 4 bits complete, so the 1 will traverse til the 1st bit from 4th.

Comment: BTW how is this called counting? I thought counting goes like 0001 00010 **00011** not **00100"*

Comment: Now it makes no sense at all. You need to provide some sample outputs for various inputs, eg. "44", "33", "666", etc, or come up with pseudocode that covers all your cases.  But I guess that's what your question is, and we can't figure it out from what you've provided so far.

Comment: Alright, let me edit it one more time with more clarity - thanks for helping

Comment: @JimGarrison I think I'm really bad at this - can you check and see if its more understandable now?

Comment: Bytes are 8 bits long, 4 bits is a Nibble.

Comment: 44 would populate 001 001 then 001 010 then 001 100 finally a shift 010 001

Comment: its an interesting problem; maybe you can start with the 2-digit number and give us a complete example (all the sequence) - and if there are variations (for the 2-digit case) need to list all sequences in complete - then we can possibly figure out the algorithm -lets stick to the 2-digit case for now

Comment: So, with the latest edit (rev. 4), it would seem that original question and edit 1 was actually **wrong**. Nobody will be able to understand your question if you leave *incorrect* information in there. I'd suggest you delete this question, then ask another one, this time providing *all* the relevant information up front, that way you *might* actually be able to get a useful answer.

Comment: @Andreas Okay, deleting this and asking a new question. thanks

Comment: @Andreas Stackoverflow won't let me ask another question in less than 90 minutes of gap, so I modified this question. Would you still recommend I ask this in a different question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I don't see a need for bitwise operators.  If you wanted to do bit-level stuff you could replace the g1 & g2 arrays with something that did shifting.  As for "counting" you're counting from 1 by powers of two (in base ten, you would have 1, 2, 4, 8, ...).  If you prefer to call it shifting 1 bit at a time that works as well.

Anyway, does this do what you had in mind?

### sample output

```
$ java Foo
digits=27
001 0001
001 0010
001 0100
001 1000
010 0001
010 0010
010 0100
010 1000
100 0001
100 0010
100 0100
100 1000
$
```

### Foo.java

```
public class Foo {
   static String g1[] = { "001",   "010",  "100" };
   static String g2[] = { "0001", "0010", "0100", "1000" };

   static void blarch( String digits ) {
      System.out.println("digits="+digits);
      int N = digits.length(); // use N for max index
      String sequence[][] = new String[ N ][];
      int counts[] = new int[ N ];
      for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
         char c = digits.charAt(i);
         sequence[i] = ( c == '7' || c == '9' ) ? g2 : g1;
         counts[i] = 0; // emphasize we're counting from zero.
      }
      boolean printStuff = true;
      while( printStuff ) {
         for( int i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
            if( i >= 1 ) System.out.print( " " );
            //System.out.print( "<i="+i+", counts[i]="+counts[i]+">");
            System.out.print( sequence[i][ counts[i] ] );
         }
         System.out.println();
         // increment, watch for overflow - done if we "overflow" on seq[0];
         for( int i = N - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
            if( ++counts[i] < sequence[i].length ) break;
            // overflow, we're done when seq#0 overflows.
            if( i == 0 ) printStuff = false;
            counts[i] = 0; // start this 'sequence' over at zero
         }
      }
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      blarch( "27" );
      //blarch( "274" );
   }
}
```

Comment: WOW!!! That's a great way of solving this problem!! Thanks man - you rock! I really can't thank you enough ^_^

Comment: glad it works for you, this was a fun one to ponder. :-)